# How to avoid one or more elements in option array of select box in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In cake php how to avoid one or more elements in option array of select box.

```
$options = array('One','Two','First','Second');

echo $this->Form->select('trial', $options);
```

Here I want to avoid 'First' and 'Second' from array, here option array is coming from DB.

```
$options = array('One','Two');
```

Is it possible to do it by  any alteration in select method of cake php(i.e `array $attributes` or anything else ) or manually search the array and drop the values  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
echo $this->Form->select('trial', array_slice($options, 0, 2));
```

**Edit:**

An alternative solution, if you don't know the order of the array, and if the values are unique, is by using [`array_search()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
unset($options[array_search('First', $options)]);
```

Or if the values aren't unique and you'd like to remove them all, then [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) could be useful:

```
$keys = array_keys($options, 'First');

foreach ($keys as $key)
{
  unset($options[$key]);
}
```

Comment: If 'First' is to be avoided, I get only value i.e 'First' in result, no array offset. So how will i solve this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you're asking. You want `array('One', 'Two', 'Second')`? You want `array('First')`?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid `array('First')` . Here `array_slice($options, 0, 2)` where 0 is offset and 2 is length. but I dont know offset of array('First'). It may come as first element or last element or any element in array.